# ReactJS window.print reloads when cancelling print

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a Link Component with an onClick which opens the print window.

It opens the print window fine, however, when I click Cancel or Print buttons on the print dialog it reloads and returns me to an error page.

My code is:

```
 <Link
    className={`${class-prefix}__print-btn`}
    onClick={() => {
        window.print()
        // return false
        }}
     >
     Print
</Link>
```

Rendered in the dom is 
`<a class="test__print-btn" href="/">Print</a>`

Thanks

Comment: `onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); window.print(); }}` (this is unrelated to printing, clicking a link with `href="/"` on the main index will reload it)

Comment: Awesome thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick={(e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    window.print()
}}
```

^ Seemed to do the trick, with help from Chris G :-)